# Regular expression for parse function arguments with functions

Tags: regex

I want to get the function arguments of string.

```
sample( 5*5 ) euros
```

This works correctly with:

```
([^\s\)]+)\(([^\)]+)\)
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/yV0wK5/1).

The problem is when I put another function inside the argument:

```
sample( decimal( 5*5 ) ) euros
```

With only a function this works with:

```
([^\s\)]+)\((.+)\)
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/qE2fR9/1).

But with two functions or more I can't get the function arguments:

```
sample( decimal( 5*5 ) ) toString(euros)
```

How can I get the function arguments with a regular expression?.

Comment: What is the regex flavor (regex library, programming language, tool)? Check out [`([^\s)]+)(\(((?>[^()]++|(?1))*)\))`](https://regex101.com/r/qE2fR9/2) - but if you are making a parser, I guess you need no regex.

Comment: I am making a parser with PHP: `preg_match('/([^\s\)]+)\((.+)\)/', 'sample( decimal( 5*5 ) ) toString(euros)', $matches)`

Comment: I'm sure @Wiktor can give you a clever regex for this, but if you really expect nested function calls to an arbitrary depth, you should consider using a parser.

Comment: Regular expressions are not able to deal with nested structures. You will have to use a different tool. There are configurable grammar parsers that can deal with these problems (for example http://pegjs.org/ for JavaScript).

Comment: The basic algorithm for your parser should be: Eat opening parentheses `(` pushing them onto a stack along with whatever content comes after them.  When you hit the first `)` you can pop the contents, and this is a function argument or set of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing a *parser* you can do without a regex. From the educational point of view, in PHP PCRE regex, you can use *recursion* and *subroutine calls*.

Have a look at

```
(?<name>[^\s()]+)(\((?<body>(?>[^()]++|(?2))*)\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE2fR9/7)

Group "name" will contain the function name and "body" group will hold what is inside the matching parentheses.

Note you need to add both `(` and `)` to the *negated character class* `(?<funcion>[^\s()]+)` because in case you have `sample(decimal(3*3))` this group will grab the substring up to the `)` (`sample(decimal`). Thus, you need to exclude both `(` and `)`.

The `(\((?<body>(?>[^()]++|(?2))*)\))` part is a capture group (with **ID=2**) that can be recursed (i.e. "repeated", "expanded" many times) with a subroutine call `(?2)`.

It matches

- `\(` - an open round bracket
- `(?<body>(?>[^()]++|(?2))*)` - Group "body" that matches zero or more sequences of:

  - `[^()]++` - 1+ characters other than `(` and `)` or
  - `(?2)` - the whole `\((?<body>(?>[^()]++|(?2))*)\)` subpattern
- `\)` - a closing parenthesis

The `(?2)` **subroutine call** necessity (as compared to **recursion** with `(?R)`) is dictated by the fact that we need to repeat/recurse a part of the pattern.

Since Group 2 is a "technical" capture group, it might be a good idea to use named capture groups for those parts we want to really use.

Comment: Just corrected - `(?1)` > `(?2)`, fixed everywhere in the answer.

Comment: Now perfect!. Thanks very much. It is a very simple parser with only four functions. Thanks for explain it.

Comment: Is It possible with `sample(decimal( 5*5 ))`? Without spaces doesn't work.[Check it](https://regex101.com/r/qE2fR9/6)

Comment: You need to fix the first capture group: `(?<funcion>[^\s()]+)(\((?<argumento>(?>[^()]++|(?2))*)\))`. I updated the answer with an explanation for the first capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Use a look ahead that specifies the next bracket char (if any) is an *open* one, and use a relucant quantifier.

This should work:

```
([^\s\)]+)\((.+?)\)(?=[^()]*(\(|$))
```